# Selecting parent element without any of its children in CSS and also in native Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, children

### Firstly, the CSS

I would like to select only the parent element without any of its children. Not sure how to do this; I have experimented with the `:not()` pseudo-class to no avail.

In this case, I am doing this because I want to reduce the brightness of the parent of an accordion on hover.

Without attempting to isolate the parent, it is something like:

```
.parent:hover {
  filter: brightness(85%);
}
```

However, this will cause all of its children to darken as well. As I also have some later `.parent` classes inside of `.parent` classes, mousing over them will double the effect.

Instead, I would like ONLY the parent to be darkened. How can I achieve this?

Note: I have not gotten anything like `.parent:hover:not(.parent *)` to work.

### And the Javascript (native)

These `.parent` elements are also accordions that work based off of toggling an `active` class on them via a click listener in Javascript. Of course, this means that I activate the accordion on the `.parent` element when clicking on its children in the same manner that the brightness works.

So how can I either a) add the click listener to elements with the `.parent` class and not their children, or b) check if a child element in the `.parent`-classed element was clicked on to trigger the listener?

Current code:

```
var accordians = document.getElementsByClassName("accordian");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < accordians.length; i++) {
  accordians[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var acc = this;
    acc.classList.toggle("active");
    // sitelist-container elements are "expanded" when the accordions are clicked
    var sitelist = acc.getElementsByClassName("sitelist-container")[0];
    if (sitelist.style.display == "") {
      sitelist.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      sitelist.style.display = "";
    }
  });
}
```

Any help for the CSS or for the Javascript would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: 
Thank you for the feedback about using the background color instead of a brightness filter. It actually looks better overall when using this strategy.

However, I still have an issue... how can I make it so that this styling only takes place when I hover over the parent element and not its children elements? Is this at all possible, or should I fundamentally redesign how I am attacking this problem?

Comment: To the time that I'm writing this comment, in `CSS` there is **NO** parent selector. Only `JavaScript` can do it for you.

Comment: *"I would like to select only the parent element without any of its children."* Stop right there. That is not how CSS works and not really ever something that you need to do. What you are ***really*** saying is that you want to ***style*** (not select) just a parent element and not its children. There's a big difference there. This would be done by selecting the parent (along with whatever descendants it has) and then, if you didn't want the descendants to also get that styling, you'd need to style them separately.

Comment: @ths I don't believe OP is looking for a parent selector, unless I'm misunderstanding, but rather trying to circumvent `filter` inheritance (applying a `filter` the parent, without affecting the children). OP, if I am correct in that assumption, then the answer is that you cannot do this. You can change your HTML or try some janky workarounds regarding positioning to "look" like things are nested, but the question I'd ask is this... What are you trying to achieve that this is a necessary step? See: [What is an XY Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There is no way to darken a DOM Element without affecting it's children. What you should do is darken the `background-color`, `color`, and `border-color` of just the parent. That shouldn't affect the children (mostly).

Comment: @TylerRoper see what the OP said: "I would like to select only the parent element without any of its children"

Comment: @ths Correct. OP wants to select an element that is a parent, without selecting its children. No need for a parent selector.

Comment: Here are 2 samples how-to using CSS, where the latter will not apply filter when hover the children: https://jsfiddle.net/fg2vrz9L/ ... and as you can see, the hover effect in 2nd sample is set on the `.bkg` elements, hence won't  kick in unless hovering direct. The reason you need the extra `.bkg` element is that you can't target the `.parent` when hover one of its children and therefore need it as its own element. When/If a _parent selector_ will be available, we will be able to skip the extra element though.

Answer (score 0):

For your CSS, **Unfortunately, you are unable to filter the parent without filtering the child.** So, we will reflect on a similar problem with `background-color` instead.

If you style on a parent element, it is styling the parent element, and because the [default background-color](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) is transparent, it *seems* like the rest of the elements have the same color, but **they are not**. However, by adjusting the default or simply setting the same property to a different value, you will see the problem resolved. Take a look at the following example:

```css
div * {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
  This is a paragraph about life. Life is 42. This is from the Hitchhiker's guide to the Galaxy. 
  </p>
  <p>
   This is another paragraph.
  </p>
</div>
```

Without the `div *` rule, the background-color is by default transparent. You can think of setting the `div *` or `*` as resetting the default. Then, only your parent selector is changing, and the children stay the same.

## Alternative Solution

There is another solution, that's a little wacky, but it works. You could code two `div`s that are siblings under the `body` instead of a child-parent relationship and use positioning to position the second div inside the first. Here is a working fiddle that represents this. http://jsfiddle.net/404_Error/td13ophq/

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this applies given OP's scenario. You chose to use `background-color` in your example, however there is a major difference between properties like `filter` and `opacity` as opposed to others like `background-color`, and that is that children cannot override their parent's `filter` or `opacity` property. If I do `filter: brightness(75%);` on a parent, and `filter: brightness(100%);` on a child, the child will be 75% brightness. You cannot override this due to the way the rendering engine works. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8c4wosx9/2/) for a quick example.

Comment: @TylerRoper, you are right. I should have tested it with filter first. I thought it made sense either way, they just had to apply what I explained to their problem. However, he said in the edit "Thank you for the feedback about using the background color instead of a brightness filter." I don't know if he was talking to the commenters including you, or me. I will edit my answer. Thanks for telling me.